# Protocol buffers and UTF-8

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, protocol-buffers, portability

The history of Encoding Schemes / multiple Operating Systems and Endian-nes have led to a mess in terms of encoding all forms of string data (--i.e., all alphabets); for this reason protocol buffers only deals with ASCII or UTF-8 in its string types, and I can't see any polymorphic overloads that accept the C++ wstring. The question then is how is one expected to get a UTF-16 string into a protocol buffer ?

Presumably I need to keep the data as a wstring in my application code and then perform a UTF-8 conversion before I stuff it into (or extract from) the message. What is the simplest - Windows/Linux portable way to do this (A single function call from a well-supported library would make my day) ?

Data will originate from various web-servers (Linux and windows) and will eventually ends up in SQL Server (and possibly other end points).

-- edit 1--

Mark Wilkins suggestion seems to fit the bill, perhaps someone who has experience with the library can post a code snippet -- from wstring to UTF-8 -- so that I can gauge how easy it will be.

-- edit 2 --

sth's suggestion even more so. I will investigate boost serialization further.

Comment: Most libraries won't deal with std::wstring because the standard makes no guarantees about it's encoding and the size of it's characters varies greatly across implementations. Also, refering to a string as 'unicode' is very bad practice. UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, and so on are all 'unicode.' It's better to use a specific encoding to reduce confusion.

Comment: thanks dauphic I adjusted Unicode to UTF-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be overkill, but the [ICU libraries](http://site.icu-project.org/) will do everything you need and you can use them on both Windows and Linux.

However, if you are only wanting conversion, then under Windows, a simple call to `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` can do the conversion between UTF-8 and

UTF-16.  For example:

```
// utf-8 to utf-16
MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, myUtf8String, -1,
                     myUtf16Buf, lengthOfUtf16Buf );
```

With Linux, libidn might do what you need.  It can convert between UTF-8 and UCS, which I *think* is equivalent to UTF-32 at some level.  For example:

```
// utf-8 to UCS
ucsStr = stringprep_utf8_to_ucs4( "asdf", 4, &items );
```

However, in Linux I think you might be best simply working with UTF-8.  Unless you have an existing library for UTF-16, I am not sure there is a compelling reason to use it in Linux.

Comment: I did stumble on this earlier, but at a second glance it looks more favourable -- especially since the license is not restrictive which I assumed it would be.  I will hold out for a while with accepting to see if someone posts a code snippet :P.

Answer (score 3):

The Boost Serialization library contains a [UTF-8 codecvt facet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html) that you can use to convert unicode to UTF-8 and back. There even is an example in the  documentation doing exactly that.

Comment: hmm that looks nice, it would certainly be a weaker dependency than ICU.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [UTF8-CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp):

```
// converts a utf-8 encoded std::string s to utf-16 wstring ws
utf8to16(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(ws));
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it's trivial: each `wchar_t` is one Unicode codepoint, and with trivial bitops you can find the corresponding UTF-8 byte(s). On Windows it isn't much harder, as there is an API for it: `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), input.size(), &out[0], out.size(), 0,0);`