# Protocol Buffer and UTF16 Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, buffer, protocols

How do you use Google Protocol Buffer with UTF16 Unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I will convert UTF16 to UTF8. Searching SO, I think your answer is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139752/protocol-buffers-and-utf-8)